# Javascript FormData object Ignoring some fields (under certain circumstances)

Tags: javascript

I have a dynamic form that is building and rebuilding categories based on the users input. Basically it is a product finder that narrows down the results as more categories are checked. I am mostly doing this with jQuery, but I found this piece of code that takes the form data and turns it into JSON.

```
var fData = new FormData(document.querySelector('#prodFilter'))
// Build Filters
buildFilterData(fData);


function buildFilterData(e) {
    const object = {};
    e.forEach((value, key) => {
        // Reflect.has in favor of: object.hasOwnProperty(key)
        if(!Reflect.has(object, key)){
            object[key] = value;
            return;
        }
        if(!Array.isArray(object[key])){
            obFOrject[key] = [object[key]];    
        }
        object[key].push(value);
    });

    // Stringify Result
    let formResult = JSON.stringify(object);
    params = formResult;
    return params;
}
```

This little snippet is cool because it can handle multiple checked values. I get a result like:

**{"keyword":"","product_type":"Category","product_category":["Sub-Cat1","Sub-Cat2"]}**

This is/was working great until I tried to add a keyword search box to further narrow-down results within the selected categories. As soon as I try and populate that text input it drops all the checkbox data (the categories are still checked). I am logging my parameters as the form is submitted and I get something like this:

**{"keyword":"ER 8"}**

The weird part is that if I type a keyword into the box, then start checking categories it picks up all the data and I get:

**{"keyword":"ER 8","product_type":"Category","product_category":["Sub-Cat1","Sub-Cat2"]}**

Anyone have any idea why the checkbox/radio fields are being dropped? Hopefully I have provided plenty of information, I'm happy to clarify anything I can.

Comment: What is `e` in your code (`e.forEach...`)?  How is the `search` thing working?  My gut thinks that `e` might be a list of `inputs` on the page and as you search, the dom is changing so those inputs are no longer on the page which would mean a bunch of data could be missing.  Maybe if you can answer the questions above, it'll be clearer.

Comment: Sorry, I combined some things to try and make it easier to see the bigger picture.  e should equal the fData. I am running it through a function. I'll update the post.

Comment: Drilling down into the categories is being done with radio buttons on the top-level category and then checkboxes for the sub-categories and sub-sub-categories. There is an jQuery on change event listening for the radio/checkboxes getting checked. It then fires a submit event that runs the above piece of code to collect all the form data up for processing. It's all working fine as long as it's confined to the checkboxes/radio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bunch of trial and error, we figured out that the enter submit wasn't picking up the checkboxes for some reason. It was triggering the submit event and running the subsequent processes, just not feeding all the inputs to the function in the question. The solution was to intercept the enter key and then submit the form via jQuery `.submit()`.